# Avoid users can change url id on Cakephp

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0

I want to avoid that some user can change the id of the url and he can edit another Book. 
For example: this is the original url:

```
https://www.myurl/books/edit/1
```

The user can change the number 1:

```
https://www.myurl/books/edit/41
```

I wanna the user **only** can edit his books from his country

This is my original Edit from my BooksController

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $country_id= $this->Auth->User()['country_id'];

    $book= $this->Books->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'book', 'put'])) {
        $book= $this->Books->patchEntity($book, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Books->save($book)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Success.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Error'));
        }
    }


    $this->set('_serialize', ['book']);
}
```

I tried to change this part of code:

```
$country_id= $this->Auth->User()['country_id'];
$book= $this->Books->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
```

for that:

```
$country_id= $this -> Auth -> User()['country_id'];
$book = $this->Books->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['City'],
        'conditions' => ['City.country_id' => $country_id]
    ]);
```

So, only the user can show the book from the same country. 
But I have an error: "**Record not found in table "book"**"

If I put the original edit function works perfect, but the user can change the id.
If I make above change the user can't edit any book id

Comment: Is "City" really correct there? If you follow Cake conventions, it would be Cities. Though I expect it would give you a different error message if that were the problem.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Exactly, the error will be different

Comment: Have you looked at the raw SQL that Cake generates for your query? Sometimes that's helpful; if it doesn't give you any ideas, posting it here might help someone else help you.

Answer (score 0):

> If the get operation does not find any results a
>   Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException will be raised. You
>   can either catch this exception yourself, or allow CakePHP to convert
>   it into a 404 error.

Check D[ocumentation Here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-a-single-entity-by-primary-key)

Alternatively uou can check with `find()` method with result of `first()`

```
$book = $this->Books->find([
        'contain' => ['City'],
        'conditions' => ['City.country_id' => $country_id,'Books.id'=>$id]
    ])->first();
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-the-first-result

Comment: Sorry for the later response. The problem Is that I have multiples admin that can edit their book of his country. Each admins have books. But one cannot change book from another country that where he is